# Create EditText in java MainActivity and how to retrieve editText id to getText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-sqlite

**I tried to set the id but i very confuse and don know how to get the data of the new edit text. editText can create like XML file that `@\id\blabla`. or using other ways to get the editText id to get the data?**

```
btnAddStep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             hintIngre++;
    edittTxt.setHint("Example : 1 ");
    editText.setId(hintIngre);
    parentLayout.addView(edittTxt);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `editText.setId(hintIngre);` should this be `edittTxt.setId(hintIngre);`?

Comment: @MikeT i declare the eddit text by `programmatically `. but the problem i don know how to get the id to retrieve the String data

Answer (score 0):

You may create edittext in xml like this

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:hint="exmple 1"/>
```

And getting value from it like this

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edt);
String text = editText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using same `editText` and adding multiple views to the parent. You can used xml to draw edit text or you can draw `programmatically`. 
As you are adding all the `editText` to the `parentLayout`, you can traverse the child of parent to get each edit text and you can retrieve the text by `editText.getText()`

Comment: what that mean multiple view...i cant understand that.. can give some example... i really confuse...